# Reintegration of mixed Varnas into society based on morality

Tags: scripture, dharma, dharma-shastras, untouchability, morality

While birth is a feature of mixed castes, it seems their violent nature was also discussed. Is there any text that explicitly states that a mixed Varna member with good morality can integrate into a society based on dharmashastras (Manu/YajnaValkya), Puranas, Dharmasutras, and Ithihasas?

Comment: You do have a very vague idea of varnashankaras. Many varnashankara castes like kayasthas, vaidyas, abhiras, weavers, potters, confectioners, ironsmiths, masons, animal herders, etc etc are already integrated into the mainstream society. The supposed violent nature of varnashankaras is attributed only to those who are deemed as antyajas.

Comment: Please elaborate sir! :)

Comment: While texts like Manusmriti depicts all varnashankaras as outcasts but some other texts have much more lenient attitude, dividing varnashankaras into anuloma, viloma & antyaja categories. Antyajas are considered as outcasts, while anulomas & vilomas are considered to be on par with shudras in all but name, hence being designated as sat-shudras. Most texts disagree on which castes are anuloma & viloma but are atleast united that certain castes (most notably chandalas) must be treated as outcasts.

Comment: Read this verses from Vriddhaharitasmriti to understand the distinctions between varnashankaras https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/57022/22857. I would also suggest you read History of Dharmasastra by P.V. Kane.